# Why to use return when recursively calling the same function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, python-2.7, data-structures

```
def foo(n):
    print(n)
    foo(n-1)
>>foo(5)
>>5


>>1
```

Function with return

```
def foo(n):
    print(n)
    return f(n-1)
>>5


>>1
```

Both these functions yields same result. So is it okay to not use return in such cases?

Comment: No, those functions aren't the same. One just _prints_ a value, whereas the other prints a value and_returns_ it.

Comment: They both print values, only one returns a value.

Comment: The output you posted is not the output of those functions... I think you've omitted a `while n > 0` or something like that. Also, f is not defined, it should be `return foo(n-1)`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you just want to print your output, or to actually assign it. Just printing it is fine if you just want to see your output, but how would you actually use that output later? You could copy and paste it, but that seems inefficient...

However, in your case, it looks like you just want to see the output of each call in your recursion, in which case, there is no need to assign it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case in particular it doesn't matter, it's just like making a recursive void function in other programming languages.